# referencing/linking to an entityform and passing nid/other field information through the URL

Tags: uri, nodes, entities

Thanks in advance for any help with this - I feel a bit like I'm down a rabbit hole.  I know there must be several ways to do this, but I'm running into some obstacles.

I'm trying to set up an event registration, but for various reasons, Entity Registration, Node Registration, and Signup don't work for what I'm looking for.  I have a content type "event," and I'd like to link to an entityform to allow anonymous users (not registered on the site) to sign up for events.  Ideally, information about the event would pass through the url or through using references to the entityform and populate the Event field and the Event Type field.

I tried using node reference URL and entity reference prepopulate, but ran into some major issues trying to reference/link to the actual entityform, as opposed to creating new content through a link.

I'm using entityform because of views integration, because I don't want anon folks to have to create new content (i.e. have a content type "registration" and have them create new ones to sign up), and also because I'm validating their email against an email collected through another registration form (volunteer registration, and I can't do that with the anon_email field in Entity Registrations.

One caveat - I'm building this site for a tiny non-profit, without the resources to do any real development in the future, so I'm trying to find a solution using features that already exist (or mostly exist).

Thanks so much for any suggestions/pointers! I've been stuck on this for a while now, and I know I'm probably just missing something big.

EDIT:

Found an inelegant solution by passing info through the url.   entityformurl/?event=[node:nid] did the trick. (Where my field name is event). If there is a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get everything I wanted to happen, and figured I would post it here in case anyone had similar difficulties.  Entity reference prepopulate + a views block that links to my event registration entityform.  This blog was extremely helpful: https://wunder.io/blog/simple-contact-form-per-content-item-with-entityform/2012-10-24 .

One tricky thing for me was getting my taxonomy terms to be recognized by an entity reference field.  The only field option I had was "Content: All taxonomy terms," and entity reference taxonomy term fields will only recognize the taxonomy id in the url.  So, I used views to rewrite the output of the  content: all taxonomy terms field as [term_node_tid-tid].

Really effing love tokens, views, and entity reference prepopulate right now!